# Error: data and salt arguments required [creating new users]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, crud, salt

I am a back-end beginner and just want to implement the CRUD functions for my homepage and try to send the user data to my database with a usual sign-up template. However, I keep getting the following error message: "Error: data and salt arguments required".
*This is the code for creating a new user:*

**controller.js**

```
    require('dotenv').config()
var UserDB = require('../model/model');
var UserDB2 = require('../model/testmodel');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const salt = 10;
    exports.create=(req,res)=>{

    //validate
    if(!req.body){
        res.status(400).send({message:'Empty'});
        return;
    }
    //hash password
        const hashedPassword= bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password,salt)
        //
        //new user
        const user = new UserDB({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: password
        })
    
        //save database
        user
            .save(user)
            .then(data => {
                res.redirect('/signup')
                
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                res.status(500).send({
                    message: err.message || "Mars Attacks !"
                })
            });
            
    }
```

**signup.ejs**

```
<body>
        <div class="Wrapklasse">
            <div class="derKoerper">
                <div class="dieKoerper dieKoerper-step-1 is-showing">
                    <div class="title">Sign Up</div>

                    <form action="/api/users" method="POST" id="add_user">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username*" required id="username" />
                        <input type="email" placeholder="E-Mail*" required id="email" />
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password*" required id="password" />
                        <input type="con-password" placeholder="Confirm Password*" />

                        <div class="text-center">
                            <span id="SignUp"><img src=/img/knight.jpg alt="knight" style="width:35%" class="das_icon"></span>
                            <input type="submit" />
                            
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script> src="/js/index.js"</script>
    </body>
```

**index.js**

```
  $("#add_user").submit(function(event){
        alert("Success!");
    })
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
const services = require ('../services/render');
const controller = require ('../controller/controller');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


//for use
route.get('/',services.homeRoutes);
route.get('/signup',services.signup);
route.get('/forum',services.forum);
route.get('/unterforum',services.unterforum);
route.get('/beitrag',services.beitrag);
route.get('/beitrag_erstellen',services.beitrag_erstellen);

//API
route.post('/api/users',controller.create);
route.get('/api/users',controller.find);
route.put('/api/users/:id',controller.update);
route.delete('/api/users/:id',controller.delete);
module.exports=route;
```

Unfortunately, I don't know what the fault could be.

Comment: what is the package and version you are using for bcrypt?

Comment: if you are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt
they recommend async mode instead of sync: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#a-note-on-timing-attacks

Comment: also, could you add the router code that calls that controller, and what is the content of `req.body` and `salt` right before the call to bcrypt please?

Comment: where do I find the version of bcrypt ?

Comment: @germanio I updated my request. It has to be sync.

Comment: I tried to push data into the database without bcrypt. it seems the data from the ejs never arrives the database. **{"message":"validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is required."}**

Comment: Ok so, the problem is not with bcrypt, but with the data you are getting from the html form. I would suggest you to log the content of the variables as they are being assigned values, or simply use a debugger, that will help you identify the problem.

Comment: I solved the problem. I forgot the the name-tag in the ejs. ;)

Comment: nice! congrats!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined salt rounds ("Salt" variable) and also make sure that req.body.password is not undefined

Comment: I take care of both. It still doesn't work.